# Google Trusted Store Code + WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-trusted-stores

I run an online store through Woocommerce and would like to integrate the Google Trusted Store code onto the platform. Has anyone done this before? If so, how would I fully integrate the Order Confirmation Module code?

Google explains that I must place the code on the order confirmation page but woocommerce itself operates on a lot of variables that I am not entirely comfortable with.

Code below:

```
 <!-- START Google Trusted Stores Order -->
 <div id="gts-order" style="display:none;" translate="no">
 <!-- start order and merchant information -->
 <span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
 <span id="gts-o-domain">MERCHANT_ORDER_DOMAIN</span>
 <span id="gts-o-email">CUSTOMER_EMAIL</span>
 <span id="gts-o-country">CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</span>
 <span id="gts-o-currency">CURRENCY</span>
 <span id="gts-o-total">ORDER_TOTAL</span>
 <span id="gts-o-discounts">ORDER_DISCOUNTS</span>
 <span id="gts-o-shipping-total">ORDER_SHIPPING</span>
 <span id="gts-o-tax-total">ORDER_TAX</span>
 <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
 <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date">ORDER_EST_DELIVERY_DATE</span>
 <span id="gts-o-has-preorder">HAS_BACKORDER_PREORDER</span>
 <span id="gts-o-has-digital">HAS_DIGITAL_GOODS</span>
 <!-- end order and merchant information -->

 <!-- start repeated item specific information -->
 <!-- item example: this area repeated for each item in the order -->
 <span class="gts-item">
 <span class="gts-i-name">ITEM_NAME</span>
 <span class="gts-i-price">ITEM_PRICE</span>
 <span class="gts-i-quantity">ITEM_QUANTITY</span>
 <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ID</span>
 <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
 <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_COUNTRY</span>
 <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_LANGUAGE</span>
 </span>
 <!-- end item 1 example -->
 <!-- end repeated item specific information -->

 </div>
 <!-- END Google Trusted Stores Order -->
```

Comment: Might be useful to just use a plugin for that like https://github.com/enollo/woocommerce-google-trusted-stores-integration.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the `thankyou.php` template via the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook.

```
function so_31732711_add_trusted_code( $order_id ){
 echo 'your code';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'so_31732711_add_trusted_code' );
```

But yeah, the linked plugin above seems like a better solution.